# How can solve i graph $ |z^{2}-z|≤1, z\in \mathbb{c} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

When i instead of $z$ place

$a+bi$

and multiple all i just get one inequality which i can't recognise, thereby i have no idea how could i possibly graph it.

Is it wrong just to leave it as some function of fourth grade written with $z$ without calculating it with $a + bi$ ?

Comment: Is $|z|=1$? Or is there any other information given?

Comment: The boundary is a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval): $|z||z-1|=1$. If you don't know it's properties you're going to have a very hard time sketching it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Let $z=x+iy$, then $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)$ and $$|z^2-z|=|(x^2-y^2-x)+i(2xy-y)|=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-x)^2+(2xy-y)^2}$$ $$=\sqrt{x^4+y^4+x^2-2x^2 y^2+2xy^2-2x^3+4x^2y^2+y^2-4xy^2}$$ $$=\sqrt{x^4+y^4-2x^3+x^2+2x^2y^2-2xy^2+y^2}\leq 1$$
 $$\Rightarrow 0\leq x^4+y^4-2x^3+x^2+2x^2y^2-2xy^2+y^2\leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok but the algebra will be hard. Consider the edge of your region:

$$|z^2-z|=1$$

$$\text{Let }z=a+bi$$

$$|(a+bi)^2-a-bi|=1$$

$$|a^2-b^2+2abi-a-bi|=1$$

Finding modulus and squaring to remove radical gives:

$$(a^2-a-b^2)^2+(2ab-b)^2=1$$

$$a^4-2a^3+2a^2b^2+a^2-2ab^2+b^4+b^2-1=0$$

Rearranging for $b$ gives:

$$b^4+(2a^2-2a+1)b^2+a^4-2a^3+a^2-1=0$$

This is a quadratic in $b^2$

$$b^2=\frac{-(2a^2-2a+1)\pm\sqrt{(2a^2-2a+1)^2-4(a^4-2a^3+a^2-1)}}{2}$$

$$b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-2a^2+2a-1\pm\sqrt{4a^2-4a+5}}{2}}$$

This gives a shape vaguely like an ellipse but it isn't one.

[WolframAlpha Graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sqrt((-2x%5E2%2B2x-1%2Bsqrt(4x%5E2-4x%2B5))%2F2)%20real)